# Symmetry in poles and zeroes

Tags: laplace-transform

This question is specifically about zeroes in $X_1(s)$ and $X_3(s)$ in the shown diagrams. Attached snapshot contains complete problem & solution.

Since the poles($\color{blue}{\times}$) are at $-1,1$, easy to guess that the denominator of the laplace transform will be $(s+1)(s-1)$. I think this is the reason they're writing the partial fraction form as $$\dfrac{A}{s+1}+\dfrac{B}{s-1}$$

I get so far. No issues.
But next they're setting $A=B$ for a single zero($\color{blue}{\circ}$) at $s=0$ condition, why are they doing this ? Numerator can have function of $s$ as a factor, right ?

Similarly they're setting $A=-B$ for no zeroes condition. How does this work ?

(To find zeroes, we set the numerator to 0 and solve. I'm wondering how setting A=B is equivalent to setting the numerator to 0.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X_3(s) = \dfrac{A}{s+1}+\dfrac{A}{s-1}= \dfrac{2As}{(s+1)(s-1)}$$

So $X_3(0) = 0$.

$$X_1(s) = \dfrac{A}{s+1}+\dfrac{-A}{s-1}= \dfrac{-2A}{(s+1)(s-1)}$$

So $X_1(s)$ only has zeros at $\infty$.

Comment: Ah  I see now you're indeed setting the numerator equal to 0. $2As = 0 \implies s=0$. For $X_1(s)$, there are no finite zeroes. Thank you so much :) Also does  the common factor in the numerator doesn't exist because, from the given diagrams, there are no zeroes in common ?

Comment: By common factor I mean something like this

$$(s^2-2)\left(\dfrac{A}{s+1}+\dfrac{B}{s-1}\right)$$

Comment: The diagrams didn't show any zeros at $s =\pm1$, so your "common factor" isn't there.  BTW, i think you meant $s^2 -1$.